# Is this example enough of a reason to implement delete and put in html5 form?

Tags: html, forms, api, endpoint, specifications

I was creating a beginner CRUD app with Django, when I discovered that I can't use PUT or DELETE in an html5 form method.
I've read this [Why are there no PUT and DELETE methods on HTML forms?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/264735) and the best answer was about the deliberation that happened when these features where considered for implementation.

**TLDR:** it hasn't been implemented yet
and it seems the issue tracker for it [ISSUE-196: Define user agent http response handling behaviour](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/tracker/issues/196) states that it's a closed issue

#### So here is the example where having the put and delete form methods can be very useful.

my django html file is like this
**TLDR:** don't read this, this isn't a Django related question, read the simplified below

```
{% block content %}
<h1 class="text-center">Task List</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for task in my_task_list%}
            <li class="m-3">
                id:{{task.id}} name:{{task.name}}
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                     <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'view_task' task.id %}">view</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">update</button>
                    <label type="button" class="btn btn-danger" for="submit_delete">delete</label>
                </div>
                <form action="{% url 'view_task' task.id%}" method="DELETE" style="display: none">
                <input type="submit" id="submit_delete" value="deletarrase" >
                </form>
            </li>    
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<a href="{% url 'form' %}" class="btn btn-warning">
<span class="h5">+</span> add task</a>
{% endblock content %}
```

##### simplified

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/tasks/{{id}}" method="DELETE">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<!-- where {{id}} is replaced by the template engine  -->
```

Isn't the ability to -for lack of a better word- activate the endpoint of an API a reason enough to implement a feature like this. it prevents the need to use another technology (JS ajax here).

you can use logical endpoint paths to perform operations like create on `/task`. delete,
read, update on `/task/{{id}}` with html only it ensures endpoint best practices.
no need to create other paths like `/tasks/update/{{id}}` `/tasks/delete/{{id}}` in case you wanna use html only.

Comment: I mean... maybe it is, maybe it isn't? What do you hope to gain from asking if it's reason to implement it here? We didn't write the HTML5 spec

Comment: Insight, opinions, something I'm missing, info about why there is no update on this topic since 2013 , and -this is wishful thinking- to get it implemented. this is my first question here. Thanks for commenting @Nick , I appreciate it.